# Use WiFi adapter for both AP broadcast and receive?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-access-point

I have a situation where I have dumb devices/sensors that have limited capability to connect to WiFi. Unfortunately, the guest network requires some type of basic OS to handle the capture web portal thing and the devices are too dumb to assign username and passwords for the secure network. I could use a laptop as a WiFi hotspot for the devices but I **cannot** use the Ethernet LAN to supply (secure) internet to the laptop to broadcast. I would like grab WiFi from the guest network and pipe it out the devices. Can I do that with a single WiFi NIC?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, yes, but not guaranteed. It's only available with some NICs.

Also, both "AP" and "client" will need to stay on the same frequency due to sharing a single radio (so the "client" part cannot easily roam between APs anymore). And it'll result in lower speeds as the radio now has to spend half the time receiving data from upstream, and half the time forwarding it to your sensors.

(It might be better to buy a second USB-connected Wi-Fi adapter.)

On Windows, I've seen some laptops show a "Microsoft virtual Wi-Fi" adapter thing which seems to make use of Wi-Fi Direct capabilities to run an access point alongside the usual client. I have not tried using it myself.

On Linux, running `iw phy` will show you the available modes. For example...

```
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
```

...means that you should be able to have 1 "managed" (client) wdev *and* 1 "AP" wdev running on the same phydev, through some creative use of `iw add`.